# How to get all the factors of a number n when I know all the factors of the square root of n?

Tags: python

I have an algorithm that returns a list of all the factors of the `n` but only checks up to `sqrt(n)`. However, I am aware that one can get the factors of `n` using only the list of factors of `sqrt(n)`.

Function:

```
def get_factors(n):
    sqrtn = floor(sqrt(n))
    factors = []

    factors.append(1)
    for factor in range(2, sqrtn):
        if n % factor == 0:
            factors.append(factor)
    factors.append(sqrtn)
    
    return factors
```

The code above returns `[1, 2, 4, 5, 10]` for an input of `n=100`, but I need to ***manipulate the list returned after the function call*** and make it `[1, 2, 4, 5, 10, 20, 25, 50, 100]` (all the factors of `n`). I only have a vague idea of that the list returned by the function is only the left-half of the whole list of factors. How would I approach this programatically?

Comment: As far as I remember checking up to `sqrt(n)` is a way to find all *prime* factors

Comment: The more useful thing would be the prime factors: `[2^2, 5^2]`, then you can just double all the exponents get any combination of factors with all exponents less o r equal to max: `[2^0*5^0, 2^1*5^0, ..., 2^2*5^2]`

Comment: While implementing the @schwobaseggl idea, You will end up on the same complexity. So you should the standard algorithm find all the factors of a number.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think that you're looking for this:

```
start = -2 if n // factors[-1] == factors[-1] else -1
factors.extend(n // f for f in factors[start::-1])
```

For any pair of numbers `n = a * b`, it must be the case that one of `a, b` must be less than or equal to `sqrt(n)` and one must be greater than or equal to it. Rearranging the definition gives `a = n // b`, where `//` is Python's floor division operator that guarantees that your result stays an integer.

Notice that I suggest iterating over the list backwards. This has two advantages in your case:

1. As the first factor decreases, the second factor increases, giving you the second half of the list in increasing order.
2. It is unwise to modify a list during iteration. This applies to an explicit loop or to the lazy iterator I am passing to `extend` here. Getting a slice of the list effectively makes a copy, so you are no longer modifying in-place.

For your concrete example:

```
>>> factors = [1, 2, 4, 5, 10]
>>> n = 100
>>> start = -2 if n // factors[-1] == factors[-1] else -1
>>> factors.extend(n // f for f in factors[start::-1])
>>> factors
[1, 2, 4, 5, 10, 20, 25, 50, 100]
```

And another:

```
>>> factors = [1, 5, 13]
>>> n = 325
>>> start = -2 if n // factors[-1] == factors[-1] else -1
>>> factors.extend(n // f for f in factors[start::-1])
>>> factors
[1, 5, 13, 25, 65, 325]
```

Answer (score 0):

> How would I approach this programatically?

You don't. You are asking a *different* question: the algorithm above is a partial algorithm and will return an unusual list (neither the *prime* factor list, nor the *full* factor list).

The prime factor list would be [2, 5]; the prime factor with multiplicity would be [(2,2),(5,2)]. This is the list you need to start from, and the algorithm is slightly different from the one above.

(You can use the algorithm you *do* have to get the list with multiplicity: if you know that 2 is a factor, look how many times you can divide 100 by 2 with a remainder of 0. You see you can only do this twice; then the multiplicity of 2 is 2).

From the list with multiplicities, you would get the expanded "prime" factor list [ [ 2, 4 ], [ 5, 25] ].

Then picking all combinations from all subsets (i.e. from 0 to all elements of [ 2, 4 ] one after the other, multiplied with 0 to all [ 5, 25 ] one after the other) will give you your answer:

```
- -  = 0 (discarded - or replaced with 1, even if it's not strictly speaking a *factor*)
- 5  = 5
- 25 = 25
2 -  = 2
2 5  = 10
2 25 = 50
4 -  = 4
4 5  = 20
4 25 = 100 (possibly discarded; this too is an atypical *factor* of 100)
```

An inefficient but quick and dirty solution would be to replace

```
sqrtn = floor(sqrt(n))
```

with

```
sqrtn = n
```

and explore the full range in o(n).

Comment: I think OP's question is much simpler than what you're reading into it.

Answer (score 0):

You can just do

```
def get_factors(n):
    n=floor(n)
    factors = []
    factors.append(1)
    for factor in range(2, n):
        if n % factor == 0:
            factors.append(factor)
    factors.append(n)
    
    return factors
```

Comment: Isn't he asking for all factors of the given number?

Comment: He's saying given the factors up to `sqrt(n)`, compute the factors past that.